# Getting OnStreamError while putting live audio input to byte array and sending as XMPP message

Tags: c#, xml, audio, xmpp, openfire

I am trying to capture live audio from microphone and convert it to string and send to XMPP client. My server is Openfire. My client is OK for text messages, but when I convert streamed byte array to string and send as XMPP message I am getting OnStreamError error`base {agsXMPP.Xml.Dom.Element} = {<stream:error xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><xml-not-well-formed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams" /></stream:error>}` I tried to send converted data (audio>>>byte[]>>>>string) manually as a text but not sent as well. This message also blocks normal text messaging. Here is my code

```
private void SendMessage(Command cmd, Jid to)
    {
        try
        {                
            Data msgToSend = new Data();

            msgToSend.strName = xmpp.Username;   
            msgToSend.cmdCommand = cmd;        
            msgToSend.vocoder = vocoder;       

            byte[] messageB = msgToSend.ToByte();
            var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(messageB);
            //byte[] reConverted = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str);
            agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message message = new agsXMPP.protocol.client.Message(new Jid(lbxContacts.SelectedItem.ToString()),
                              MessageType.chat,
                              str);

            xmpp.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do XML escaping on the string before it is sent (and decode it on the receiving end), although the better way would be to simply convert the byte array to base64 encoding and skip the conversion to a string altogether.

You may also run into size limits creating overly large stanzas.  The better way to send large chunks of binary data is to use [Bytestreams](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0065.html).  There is also a protocol specifically for doing [live audio](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0167.html#intro).

You should check if the library you are using supports these protocols.